# Azure Search Invalid Auth Token

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azureportal

Im currently in the process of building a webapp that utilizes azure cognitive search to get data from a cosmos db container I have set up. For the past 3 days, the azure search has been working perfectly, and ive been able to access the search container from the azure portal just fine. Today I was working on my application and I started getting 400 response codes from my get requests to the azure search URI.

I went to the portal and was prompted with the following message when I clicked on "overview" in the azure search container.

[image]

Clicking it simply makes it disappear. Im now unable to see any usage statistics, and unable to enter queries through the search explorer. I then replaced the 'api-key' header in my get request to the api key instead of the admin key, and am able to now get search results.

I know the azure search itself is working but it seems that the portal is completely broken. I cant change any settings, cant add any indexes, and cant search through the search explorer on the portal.

Here is what I have tried so far to fix:

- close browser and reopen - didnt work
- restart computer - didnt work
- refresh tab - didnt work
- log out of microsoft, and log back in - didnt work
- deleted and recreated a new azure search container - didnt work
- had coworker attempt to log into a completely different resource group and create a new search, but he saw the same exact auth failed error that I was seeing.

When I check my access to the database, under the IAM tab, my role is "contributor" which grants me full access to the search container, so this should not be an issue.

Im completely stuck and being unable to index a field is holding me back. If you need any more relevant information, please let me know.

Comment: this seems to be a portal problem. Microsoft is aware and should solve it in the near future

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio quite weird, I checked their services status page and nothing was marked as having issues, and no google search would return anything. Guess ill just have to wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Microsoft is aware of the issue and a correction is coming:

[image]

Comment: Just saw that half an hour ago. Thank you!